# Vibrate on notification in Silent Mode

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications

When my iPhone is in Silent Mode from the side switch I only ever get vibrations when specific apps receive a notification, such as TweetBot/Facebook, however I'm not getting them from quite a few other apps such as Fallout Shelter/Spotify. I was under the impression that enabling Sounds under the Notification preferences switched on the vibration notification when the phone is silent, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but I can't see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's under the app's discretion whether to alert the user with vibration when silent mode is enabled. You can contact the app developer's through the link on the App Store page.

For notifications from apps like Fallout Shelter, I like the fact that the notification doesn't cause a vibration as its there when I next check the lock screen and I regard those notifications as less important (I don't need to be interrupted for those kinds of notifications) although I agree there should be an option to enable/disable this by the user. This would have to be something implemented within the specific app.

Comment: That's great, thanks. I took a look at the APN docs and thought it looked that way, nice to have confirmation though!